# Mobile website that display an autoplay video in a banner (iOS)

Tags: ios, html, video, mobile, banner

I went to this website on my ipad mini and saw that there was a TD Bank banner at the bottom of the page auto playing a video.

For those interrested to try on a mobile, get your tin foil hats. The site is [abovetopsecret.com](http://www.abovetopsecret.com)

Anyone has any idea how it can be done? I haven't found much and I bet someone here knows how to do this stuff.

Comment: https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video